# Thinkpad T590 and HP USB-C G5 Dock with two 1440p screens not working on Fedora 33

Tags: fedora, display, thinkpad

I'm trying to run two 1440p monitors on Fedora 33 on my Thinkpad T590 and HP USB-C G5 dock, but it's failing to enable it. It works with something like 1440p on the primary monitor and 720p on the secondary.

From the journal:

```
Jul 02 10:53:02 devcli49.devclients.outpost24.com /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2229]: (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 5120x1440 stride
Jul 02 10:53:02 devcli49.devclients.outpost24.com /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2229]: (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: No space left on device
Jul 02 10:53:02 devcli49.devclients.outpost24.com /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2229]: (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 2560x1440 stride
```

**Edit**: Some additional information is that this only seems to happen in Linux. When I start the laptop with everything plugged in then during the BIOS boot screen both screens are on with 1440p although in mirrored mode.

Comment: When we each got two 1440p monitors at the office, we also got new thunderbolt-based docking stations. Some of my colleagues that are more into that stuff said someting about USB-C not supporting the bandwidth needed for two different 1440p monitors. (I have a T480s, my colleagues have a mix of other T4x0's and a few macs)

Comment: Other colleagues have T4x0's I believe and it works for them with the same dock. So maybe some setting in BIOS I can't find.. it's not the only dock I've had problems with. The docks state that they should be able to drive two 4K monitors so two 1440p should be fine